# Difference between ExitCodeGenerator and System.exit(0)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exit-code

I recently learned that the proper way to shut down a Spring Boot application is this:

```
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator() {
        return new ExitCodeGenerator() {
            @Override
            public int getExitCode() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)));
    }
}
```

This should return an exit code of 0, or whatever I configure it to return in the `getExitCode()` method. My question is - what is the difference between doing the approach above vs the one below:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The application seems to be shut down in exactly the same way by both approaches, at least in the console. So what's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

The ExitCodeGenerator is used if you wish to return a specific exit code when SpringApplication.exit() is called. This exit code can then be passed to System.exit() to return it as a status code.

For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExitCodeApplication {

@Bean
public ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator() {
    return new ExitCodeGenerator() {
        @Override
        public int getExitCode() {
            return 42;
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication
            .exit(SpringApplication.run(ExitCodeApplication.class, args)));
}

}
```

Also, the ExitCodeGenerator interface may be implemented by exceptions. When such an exception is encountered, Spring Boot will return the exit code provided by the implemented getExitCode() method.

Comment: Seems like I can return a specific exit code the other way as well. I just did `System.exit(42)` at the after the `SpringApplication.run()` method and the application ended with an exit code of 42.

Answer (score 3):

Of course for you examples, this does not matter. But what this allows is to "glue" a certain Exception to a certain exit code. Spring, by default, catches all Exceptions that your code might throw - if such an Exception also implements `ExitCodeGenerator` - that will be used to output the exit code you have provided.

Of course, you can do that mapping by hand, but it's *a lot* more verbose and harder to maintain; Spring makes this easier. Once that is understood, you might also be interested in `ExitCodeExceptionMapper` that can map an underlying `Exception` (with let's say multiple error messages) to *different* error codes.

Comment: Can you please update this answer and provide some example ?